# diff two XML files

Tags: xml, diff

I have xml document like this:

```
<datatypes xmi:id="ID_01"</datatypes>
<datatypes xmi:id="ID_02">
  <fields xmi:id="ID_03">
    <datatype xmi:idref="ID_01"></datatype>
  </fields>
</datatypes>
```

I also have spesil tool that change xml files. It allows you to add new nodes atributes and change old one, but after use it all IDs change.

Afte use tool:

```
<datatypes xmi:id="ID_11"</datatypes>
<datatypes xmi:id="ID_12">
  <fields xmi:id="ID_13">
    <datatype xmi:idref="ID_11"></datatype>
  </fields>
  <something_new/>

</datatypes>
```

I want compare two xml files and find only **< something_new/>**. When i use standart diff i see all changes (id too)

Are there easy way to solve this problem?
if not, what langudge(IDE) I should use for write such a comparison fastert.

Comment: XMLUnit example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280976/looking-for-a-xml-comparison-tool/14287099#14287099

Answer (score 0):

You can try [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) .

[XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) has a [diff](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/Diff.html) feature

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the documentation for Spesil (Is this a library? I couldn't find documentation for this anywhere) to see if this behavior what is expected, there could be some configuration which stops id number from being replaced...

If there is a schema for this XML message you could use JAXB to un-marshal your XML into a model which you could access, you could pass the before and after (marshal both) then write a routine to look for changes). This would be a good way to do it if you needed to access further attributes/elements of the changes as you would be able to access changes as objects (not just text changes as would be the case with a diff tool). I guess it depends on how you intend to use the changes!

JLove